# Implicit reference to object under construction is not valid when calling another constructor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am trying following Within my MVC Controller:

```
Private ProductRepoitory As IProductRepository
Sub New()
    Me.New(New productsRepository(New ModelStateWrapper(Me.ModelState)))
End Sub

Sub New(ByVal repo As productsRepository)
    ProductRepoitory = repo
End Sub
```

However this line throws following Error message:

```
Me.New(New productsRepository(New ModelStateWrapper(Me.ModelState)))
```

**Implicit reference to object under construction is not valid when calling another constructor**

I understand, I am calling a Constructor within a Constructor, and other Constructor expects a parameter, its the parameter part where it is failing.

Removing "me" does not help, I need to pass my Controller's ModelState as a parameter to ModelStateWrapper Class, any other workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

Before you call `Me.New()`, your object hasn't been constructed yet.
Therefore, you can't access `Me`.

Comment: @highwingers: `ModelState` is part of `Me`.  You can't access it, period.

Comment: This complicates inheriting from a base controller with vb.net and using DI.  Using his example, what is the correct syntax to get around the self centered "Me" vb.net demands?

Comment: @JoshYates1980: You cannot access your object before its base classes are fully constructed.  This is common to most / all OO languages.  You need to call the base ctor first.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Me.ModelState` when creating a constructor chain with `Me.New`. The alternative is to create an 'initialize' method like this:

```
Private ProductRepoitory As IProductRepository
Sub New()
    Me.Initialize(New productsRepository(New ModelStateWrapper(Me.ModelState)))
End Sub

Sub New(ByVal repo As productsRepository)
    Me.Initialize(repo)
End Sub

Private Sub Initialize(ByVal repo As productsRepository)
    Me.ProductRepoitory = repo
End Sub
```

Also note, unless `Me.ModelState` is a property and the getter method does some sort of initialization of the value, then when you pass it into the `Initialize` method, `Me.ModelState` will be null. It's likely this kind of pattern will cause some problems for you later on, so you may want to consider refactoring your code a bit.